# PHP - MYSQL : Multiple tables from one prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to call a stored procedure from mysql that look something like this one:

```
insert into c select n,o,d

select * from a

select * from b
```

and then call it from php with function that will warp it:

```
$data = query("call my_procedure(?,?,?)","iii",[1,2,3])
```

finally in want to get the $data to be

```
[
   [row_from_a,row_from_a,row_from_a,row_from_a],
   [row_from_b,row_from_a,row_from_b,row_from_b]
]
```

Is it possible ?

With all of my tries in the last month i could only get the first select...

Comment: mysqli works only with one query

Comment: so did you define your stored procedure already?

Comment: What you described is a completely wrong way of using a database. Here's a question that you should have asked yourself before all of this - **why**?

Comment: Since you've already wrote some procedure that gives you the first select, can you paste the full code?